# Share codebase using common Sdk module in create react app Reactjs application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, create-react-app, monorepo

I want to start a new app that will have both web and reactnative interfaces.

I decided to move all business -non enviroment dependent- code into a third package -aka sdk- that i can share between both react & react native .

So my project now has 4 modules

1. Web -- created with cra
2. Sdk -- mainly redux + redux saga + react containers + Hoc's
3. Mobile -react native
4. Server - nodejs express api.

   - All web, mobile and server will depend on Sdk module.
   - sdk module will depend on server module -mainly to impory mocks and data interfaces.

Is there any standard way to achieve such structure ?

Most probably i would love to

- use yarn workspaces to hoist all node-modules into one folder to avoid reinstalling packages in every project
- i will be working in all 4 projects at same time, so i need hotreload to be aware of this.

** challenges im facing **

1. Cra doesnot transpile code outside src folder so although web project does refresh qhen i make changes on sdk. It cannot understand es6 code.
2. Jest also doesnot understand es6 from node_modules

How can i avoid rebuilding step while working on both sdk and web modules simultaneous ?

Comment: Have you tried learna https://github.com/lerna/lerna ..

Comment: @RahilAhmad that wonnt help fixing any of challenges i mentioned above

Comment: > CRA doesn't transpile code outside of src folder - this is not a challenge for anyone, it is a misuse of a very limited 'hello-world' instrument, which does not fit real-life use cases. And `babel` config is just one example of many. Just eject it, or use some overriding tools (which is yet another hack over existing one).

Answer (score 6):

[Yarn workspace](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) sounds like a good approach for the project structure you're thinking.

You can have a `packages` directory where you can add your projects:

```
/packages
  - web
  - sdk
  - native
```

Now you can use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to watch for code changes for each of your package using `babel -w` and yarn workspace will take care of linking them together.

If the babel watchers are running, any changes that you make to the sdk will be reflected to both `web` and `native` packages. You can also club all of these together using something like [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to fire up watchers using a single command.

I have co-authored an open-source library where we follow a similar structure which you may check [here](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch). The difference in this project is that our redux logic is in a separate repo.

In order for jest to work, you can add a `test` env into your `.babelrc` file which transpiles modules. So you can add two different environments like `test` which transpiles into commonjs modules and an `es` environment which keeps ES modules so your users can take advantage of tree-shaking. [Example config](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/blob/dev/packages/web/.babelrc)

Hope this gives you a good starting point :)

Answer (score -1):

You could try a Project structure like this:

```
| package.json
|- node_modules
|- Web
 | package.json
|- SDK
 | package.json
|- Mobile
 | package.json
|- Server
 | package.json
```

Then you could install everything within the root folder and set the NODE_PATH env variable :

```
export NODE_PATH='yourdir'/node_modules
```

Comment: that wonnt help fixing any of challenges i mentioned above

Comment: you can use yarn workspaces to host on one folder with this and have a central hot reload from the root package.json

Comment: react doesnot transpile code outside src folder. so you will get "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:26)" when importing any of modules in workspace